# Admin Login redirecting after login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, url, htaccess

I have cloned my 1.9.1 install to a subdomain successfully.  However an odd behavior is occurring.  When I attempt to login to the admin, the page reloads, the login fields are blank, and I noticed that the url has redirected me to the original domains url.

`magedev.example.com/index.php/admin` (enter credentials, click login)

the page reloads as:

```
www.example.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/9654a53e6793hu57dys624b51a6673e362/
```

I've changed secure and unsecure URL's in the DB.  I deleted all entries in `core_url_rewrite`.  Is this an `.htaccess` issue?  I swapped out the sub-domain where I thought I should below.I haven't changed anything else here and probably should, but am unsure exactly what is needed.  There's much more to the file but this seemed to be the only part that could be involved?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.com\/" [R=301,L]

SetEnvIf Host www\.website\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host www\.website\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^website\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^website\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

became

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magedev.website.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magedev\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magedev.website.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/magedev\.website\.com\/" [R=301,L]


SetEnvIf Host magedev\.website\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host magedev\.website\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^website\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^website\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

The first section redirected me to the old site immediately.  The edit behaved as mentioned above.  It takes my credentials, reloads the page from the old url and wants me to log in again.  Clearly I am missing something.  I put in the stock fresh install `.htaccess`, and its still redirecting.  I've searched the DB for any instance of the old domain name, and it only appears in an extension that isn't relevant to the admin loading.

Comment: disbale the .htaccess file and upload the default one comes with magetno folder and then check

Comment: did you change the base url in database core_config_data table

Comment: Yes for both secure and unsecure.  I've replaced the with stock .htaccess.  Deleted cache again.  Still redirecting.

Comment: One thing to note is that I am getting security warnings for the certificate when I try to go to the subdomain as its not covered under the main domains cert?  I have to bypass that to proceed to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Do the followings:

1. According to magento takes all **config data from cache folder** you have to clear the `magentodir/var/cache` - including all subfolders - to be sure the new config is taken.

If above not works then do the below step:

2. also login to Phpmyadmin or any database method to empty the table core_url_rewrite (remember back up it first to make sure you have no risk).

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I had previously dumped the var/cache folder many times, but I did again, and additionally added all the entries in core_url_rewrite, and yet when I login to:  magedev.example.com/index.php/admin it reloads the page as www.example.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/9654a53e6793hu57dys624b51a6673e362/.  Same exact problem.